# Loading checkpoint shards takes too long

Tags: huggingface-transformers, h2o, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, llama

I'm very new to generative AI. I have 64gb RAM and 20GB GPU. I used some opensource model from Huggingface and used Python to simply prompt it with out of box model and displaying the result. I downloaded the model to local using `save_pretrained` and trying to load the model from local there after. It works. But everytime I run the python file it takes more than 10 mins to display the results.

There is a step `Loading checkpoint shards` that takes 6-7 mins everytime. Am I doing anything wrong? why it has to load something everytime even though the model is refered from local.

I tried using `local_files_only=True, cache_dir=cache_dir, low_cpu_mem_usage=True, max_shard_size="200MB"` , none solved the time issue .

How to prompt the saved model directly without so much delay as user usable. Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: can you please add more details so it's reproducible?

Comment: i have a similar issue, i assumed after downloading the pretrained model and running it once it would somehow be able to do fast loading, but every time i get into the loading checkpoint shards and waiting 10 minutes at least

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem and I fixed it by setting `safe_serialization=True` when using the `save_pretrained()` method. Hope this works for you. However, I do want to know what was going on when loading a model with a vanilla .bin format.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from the `from_pretrained` method reloading the checkpoint shards each time your script runs.

To circumvent this, consider running the code in a Jupyter notebook, which allows you to load the model once in a separate cell using `from_pretrained` and keep the kernel running. Subsequent uses of the model for generating outputs can be done in other cells.

Here's how you can set it up:

```py
# Cell 1: Load the model (Run this once)
from transformers import YourModelClass
model = YourModelClass.from_pretrained("path/to/local/model")
```

```py
# Cell 2: Use the model (Run this as needed)
output = model.generate_some_output()
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method:
`model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_path, device_map="auto",  trust_remote_code=True).eval()`

It may work.